# EFI partition Macbook

Tags: boot, partitioning, mac, grub-efi

I know this question has probably come up earlier but I couldn't find any article that's exactly my case.

Therefore I ask you guys.

I just installed the newest Ubuntu on my mac, the issue is I do not have any EFI partition and I wonder if I can create that afterwards of the installation?

Can you guys please help because I do not dare to turn off my pc right now, have tried for a week with different distros.

When I boot it will come a white screen for 30 seconds before I get to the grub menu.

It's really annoying since I just put in a new ssd in this old MacBook.

Please guys help me with a nice solution and guide here!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ESP after installation if the installer did not make one:

1. Get your Ubuntu installation media, and boot it. Chose the option to *Try Ubuntu without installing* (because we will **not** be re-installing Ubuntu).
2. When the Ubuntu live has booted, go to the applications list, and find and launch **Gparted**.
3. Inside Gparted, find the disk on which Ubuntu is installed on and select it from the dropdown at the top.
4. You should see an `ext4` partition on this disk (and possibly a `swap` partition as well). Resize the `ext4` partition so that there is 500MB of unallocated space afterwards. In this space, make a `FAT32` partition.
5. Now assign the `esp` flag to the partition.
6. Apply all the operations to confirm the changes.
7. Now take note of the partition name (eg: `/dev/sda2`).
8. Now you need to edit a file on the `ext4` partition (mount it if it not already mounted (may require rebooting the installation media)).
9. In **Files**, go to `/media/ubuntu/LABEL_OF_EXT4_PARTITION/etc/fstab` (label will be different to name (might even be a hash)). Edit the `fstab` file with the text editor.
10. Add a line to the end of the file with the following line: `/dev/sdxy   /boot/efi    fat32    defaults    0 2`, where x and y refer to the partition name (such as a2 in `/dev/sda2`).
11. Save and close.
12. Finally, ensure the mountpoint exists. Go to `/media/ubuntu/NAME_OF_EXT4_PARTITION/boot` and look for a folder named `efi`. If one does not exist, create one.

This should give you a working ESP for Ubuntu. You should now be good to reboot normally.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!  But i cant really find the ext4 and stuff like that when i open Gparted. Only thing i can see on the harddrive is              \dev\sda2 with mount point ubuntu and the whole disk space on 232 gb. above this it is one partition more and that is /dev/sda1 with file system grub2 core.img on 1mb.  Thats it.  I apoligies for my noobieness here and i hope you will help me further

Comment: @Robin I presume Ubuntu is on your main hard disk. The biggest partition is normally Ubuntu. It should say `ext4` next to it. This is the partition you will resize - making it 500MB smaller, and leaving 500MB of unallocated space, in which you will create the ESP (formatted FAT32). It might not necessary be `/dev/sda2`, I was just using this as an example - it will tell you the name of it in Gparted.

Comment: Your are really helpfull, thanks. But it doesnt stand ext4, it stands lvm.  Anyway if u will resize that it comes up 4 lines, excactly what should i put in the following>free space preceding-new size-free space following-align to. what should i put in them

Comment: But thats the weird thing here, i didnt encrypt through the installation, 100 % sure

Comment: @Robin I will research into that, there might be an answer to it on this site

Comment: I will try a reinstallation again to see if i get rid of it :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: ubuntu partition]

I don't know if you can really open this link

[image]

Comment: `lvm` suggests you used encryption during the installation. I would advise not encrypting everything, but encrypting 1 folder inside your home folder where sensitive stuff will be stored, and yes, set "Free Space Following" to 500, it will automatically resize the rest.

Comment: i didnt encrypt in the installation

Comment: OK then not sure why it says LVM I will research into that

Comment: Im sorry fo all this questions but when it comes to step 9 i cant find it whatsoever. When i hit media i just get one iption and that is the cdrom i have the ubuntu on, is that wrong right?

Comment: That you have a bios_grub partition, not an ESP - efi system partition is because you installed in BIOS boot mode to a gpt partitioned drive. Be sure to boot install flash drive in UEFI boot mode to install in UEFI boot mode. LVM is logical volumes. The volumes inside will contain the ext3 & swap partitions as volumes. You have to use different tools with LVM. LVM often used on servers and is require for full drive encryption on desktops. If not familiar with LVM better to start with standard partitions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm